# Getting the author name on author archive page

Tags: php, archives, author

My template not work for author name on author archive. I tried change to get_the_author but nothing changed. Hope someone help me out. Thank in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [the related Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) page? Also, please don't post _screenshots_ of code. Type that bits into your question as [edit]. Thanks. ... and why the heck did you "scratch out" your textdomains?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you trying to do with if-else statement, but to display author name with their published post link use this code:

```
<span>Article posted by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
```

Tweak it according to your need.
One more thing: You need to call the_author_posts_link() function within the while loop (Yes, the same while loop, which is used to print the_title and the_content).